# link text sticks out of the div

Tags: css

to make it simple, i've got following code:

```
<div>
     <a>view all your links</a>
</div>
```

the width of the div is very small so the text "all your links" sticks out of the div. how do i do to have a new line after "all your" so "links" dont stick out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `max-width` property for your `a` links.

Edit: You'll likely need a `display: block` for your `a` tag as well.

Comment: the links are inserted into the div with ajax. and the link texts are selected from database.

Comment: This is still a valid answer to solve the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: To avoid confusion let me state I edited my answer after noname clarified his question.

Comment: it doesnt work!..used max-width and display block. the backgroundcolor got chopped not the text inside of it.

Comment: without more information as to the rest of your code and css, i don't know what to say, as my quick experiment works: div {background: #666;width:200px;} a {display: block; max-width: 120px;} Browser bug? What browser are you using?

Comment: my fault. i had nowrap on the links=/

Answer (score 6):

If you want to break links visually so they don't extend out of a div, you can add `word-wrap: break-word` to `a` in your stylesheet. Thus:

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified your desired result. Do you want the div to resize to accomodate the entire width of the links? If so, don't put a fixed width on it or any of its ancestor elements. Do you want the overlong links to be cut off? If so, put `overflow: hidden` in the style of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```